# Does the double negative have any implications in "very unlikely that there is no difference"

Tags: word-usage, negation

If the sentence was "likely there is no difference" it would mean that the two things are the same. When it is "unlikely there is no difference", does it mean two things are not the same?

Full paragraph as below:

> In order to reject it, we have to set up a system where it seems very unlikely that there is no difference. From a data point of view, this can be a little easier to view.

Comment: No double negative here. There's an understood *that* between 'unlikely' and 'there' **that** divides two clauses. Does it mean two things are not the same? Yes, it means **that** the two things are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

> - *It is unlikely that there is no difference*

is just the extraposed version of

- *That there is no difference is unlikely.*

And **that** is a version produced by *there*-Insertion of

- *That no difference exists is unlikely.*

which **is** a double negative, in the traditional sense of *Duplex Negatio Affirmat* ('double negation affirms'). The negative *un-* of *unlikely* governs the negative *no* of *no difference* and hence cancels it out. Logically, it's

- **¬**(`LIKELY` (**¬**(∃x) (`DIFFERENCE` (x))))
  'It's **not** likely that there is **no** *x*, such that *x* is a difference'

Which all goes to say that it's likely there's **some** difference somewhere.
If you look for it.